# Putting index on a column that gets updated frequently in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

In a postgres db, I have a table with an `UpdatedAtDate` column that I put an index on. This column also gets updated frequently. Will the index be updated every time that column is updated and could this lead to performance issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the index has to be updated whenever you update the column.

What is worse, that index will prevent [HOT updates](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/hot-updates-in-postgresql-for-better-performance/), which greatly reduce the need for autovacuum runs to get rid of old, outdated row versions.

So if you can, drop that index and set the `fillfactor` for the table to less than 100.

Answer (score 1):

Not only will that index get updated every time the value is changed, but so will every other index on that table.  If any indexed column is updated, every index is updated. That certainly can lead to performance problems.  Of course, so can the lack of an index.

Comment: With that said, is it unwise to put index on a column that is prone to frequent change?

Comment: I'd at least avoid until I had evidence it was needed.  But sometimes columns that are frequently changed are also frequently and selectively queried, and so are pretty important to index.  But sometimes they are not.